# CMake: How to treat every resource compiler warning as error and to suppress specific warnings?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, warnings, compiler-warnings

To suppress specific warning in specific source file when using [CMake](https://cmake.org) to generate **MSVC** projects I'm using something like:

```
set_source_files_properties(
    "ToursInfoMng.cpp"
  PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS "/wd4503")
```

This doesn't work for resource compiler warnings. For example for warning:

```
warning RC4206: title string too long; truncated at 256
```

I tried to use:

```
set_source_files_properties(
    "ResEs.rc"
  PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS "/wd4206")
```

but this doesn't suppress the warning.

- How to suppress resource compiler warning properly?
- How to treat resource compiler warnings which are not suppressed as errors?

I'm using `\WX` for both compiler and linker warnings setting it to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_STATIC|SHARED|EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` respectively, but I don't know how to do it for resource compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe either of these is possible. There are no documented general warning control options for the Windows Resource Compiler, just type `rc /?` to check.

You can change the Resource Compiler's flags using `CMAKE_RC_FLAGS`.

There is also a filter on `COMPILE_FLAGS` and `COMPILE_OPTIONS` that prevents them being used to pass any flags that are not defines or includes to the Resource Compiler. In principle, if you needed to, you could change the filter (`CMAKE_RC_FLAG_REGEX`) so as to be able to use these properties for more, but that would not help you in this situation.

Comment: I tried to set `/WX` to `CMAKE_RC_FLAGS` as I do for compiler and linker flags but this leads to error: `fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'winres.h'`

Comment: That's probably because rc doesn't have a /WX flag. It *does* have separate /W (warn on invalid codepage) and /X Ignore INCLUDE environment variable) flags.

Answer (score -2):

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : 4101)
// Function Here : Declare
#pragma warning(pop)
```

Then If you want **To suppress specific warnings for Visual C++**
Following this ref : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715718.aspx

Press Ctrl+F > Type "To suppress specific warnings for Visual C++".
You can find how to suppress specific warnings.

Comment: This seems to has no effect for resource compiler warnings. I tried to put `#pragma warning(disable : 4206)` in appropriate placed in `rc` file.

Comment: Then you have to explain that. However, MSDN seems to be a good reference. Do it all by yourself.